# How to change the background image with each load

Tags: javascript, html

On my login page, I want to create a function so that with each load, a new background image appears.

Comment: Do you mean a random background image appears

Comment: Did you try anything? Make a set of images, and use Math.random to generate a random number between 0 to the number of images you have. Based on that value you can set the background image.

Comment: This, I have 4 images to be displayed at random, but I am managing to display only one

Comment: It'd be great if you share the code snippet of what you have tried so far and add some context.

Comment: This is source of the one image http://painel.jovempleno.com.br/public/images/login_bg.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with onload method to body and using random to take from any array which includes of images

```js
function randombg(){
  var random= Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 0;
  var bigSize = ["url('http://placehold.it/300&text=banner1')",
                 "url('http://placehold.it/300&text=banner2')",
                 "url('http://placehold.it/300&text=banner3')",
                 "url('http://placehold.it/300&text=banner4')",
                 "url('http://placehold.it/300&text=banner5')",
                 "url('http://placehold.it/300&text=banner6')"];
  document.querySelector("body").style.backgroundImage=bigSize[random];
}
```

```css
body{
width:100;
height:100
}
```

```html
<body onload="randombg()">

</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```js
const images = ["https://images.pexels.com/photos/255379/pexels-photo-255379.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500", "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1546146477-15a587cd3fcb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80", "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/08/30/01/05/milky-way-2695569_960_720.jpg"];
//you can add as many image paths as you want

function generateRandomBackground() {
  let randomImageURL = images[Math.floor(Math.random() * (images.length))];
  console.log(randomImageURL);
  document.body.style.backgroundImage= 'url('+randomImageURL+')';
}

document.body.onload = () => {
  generateRandomBackground();  
 }
```

```css
body {
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<body>
</body>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Ideally you would provide an image already from the server-side, but if you're restricted to the client, this is one way of doing it:

```js
// Your list of background images
const backgrounds = [
  'https://picsum.photos/1024/768',
  'https://picsum.photos/1024/768',
  'https://picsum.photos/1024/768',
  'https://picsum.photos/1024/768',
  'https://picsum.photos/1024/768'
];

// Pick a random index in the list of images
const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(backgrounds.length));

// Select the random background image
const backgroundImage = backgrounds[randomIndex];

// Set the background image of the document root, in this case <html>
document.documentElement.style.backgroundImage = `url(${backgroundImage})`;
```

```css
html {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to do something like this:

```js
const imageUrls = [
  'url1',
  'url2',
  'url3'
];

const randomImageIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * imageUrls.length);
const randomImageUrl = imageUrls[randomImageIndex];

const body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];



body.style.backgroundImage = `url(${randomImageUrl})`;

console.log(body);
```

```html
<html>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```